# fetch data with two table like blow image

Tags: php, mysql

Hi i have a two tables and i want to fetch data, one table have agent_id and 2nd table has agent_id, and agent_sale record so, i just want to show data with join query so that i can get not repeat user_id with multiple sales record according to sales.

1st table - agent_sales_daily

```
id  agent_id    agent_username  userlevel   status  date
1   2           rajesh           2           1  2019-09-04
2   3           ram              2           1  2019-09-04
4   4           amit             2           1  2019-09-04
```

2st table - agent_sale

```
id  agent_id    agent_sale  status  date
1   2           300          1      2019-09-04
2   3           500          1      2019-09-04
3   3           200          1      2019-09-04
4   4           0            1      2019-09-04
5   3           600.55       1      2019-09-05
7   3           300.50       1      2019-09-05
```

i am trying like this

```
SELECT b.agent_username,a.agent_sale,b.agent_id,a.date 
FROM agent_sale a 
    left join agent_sales_daily b ON a.agent_id = b.agent_id 

$sqlQ ="SELECT b.agent_username,a.agent_sale,b.agent_id,a.date 
        FROM $sale a 
            left join $table b ON a.agent_id = b.agent_id 
$res = $conn->query($sqlQ);
```

i want output put is like 1 agent_username have multiple sales and i want show record like ram has 3 sales and show one ram and three sales record but not duplicate ram

thanks in advance[image]

Comment: i want join query so that i can get record

Comment: I suspect you would do this in PHP when displaying the data, not in the database query when fetching the data.  While looping through the results of the query and emitting output to the page, you can keep track of the current value of "agent username".  When the value changes, output it.  Otherwise, output an empty cell.

Comment: Thats a good start. Just need to close the Double Quoted String... Add a `"` after `left join $table b ON a.agent_id = b.agent_id"`

Comment: Then you will need to fetch the results, assuming the query is correct.

Comment: i solved my problem.. thanks